# How to + (addition) values (numbers) together inphp?

Tags: php, html, mysql, helper, addition

I am currently developing a tool and part of it calculates employees. I want to be able to get 12 numbers of thier row from different coloumns...

E.G.

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Data 1</th>
    <th>Data 2</th>
    <th>Data 3</th>
    <th>Data 4</th>
    <th>Data 5</th>
    <th>Data 6</th>
    <th>Data 7</th>
    <th>Data 8</th>
    <th>Data 9</th>
    <th>Data 10</th>
    <th>Data 11</th>
    <th>Data 12</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>67</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>67</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>67</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>67</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>67</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>67</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to I add all of those together to make one number in php and display it on a dashboard? (Connects to MYSQL)

Comment: How is that table created? Is it generated through php?

Comment: No, manual imput through php my admin

Comment: Company, that specializes in tailoring needs

Comment: The only php generated code would be if they changed the numbers through thier settings.

Comment: PHP is a server side language. You should use it to work with data on the server side - e.g. sum the result of a database query and display the number by generating it into the html. In your case it looks like this is a static table, so it would be better to do the math on the client, using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to get all td value and concate that and pass it to php file using ajax.

```
$('#mytable td').each(function() {
    var cellText += $(this).html();    
});
```

then pass this value to ajax call.